# Add on-premise nodes to GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

How do I add my on-premise node to my managed cluster?

I've tried doing "kubeadm join --token  " with a default-token from the ui and the cluster endpoint as ip.

Comment: hi @toon sevrin, have you managed to get to the bottom line of this? Please provide a detailed answer to your question if you managed to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can add an on-prem node to your GKE cluster if you manually configure the kubelet (basically what kubeadm makes nice and easy).

Your cluster may not work as expected though unless you also create a VPN connection between the on-prem node and your cloud network where the rest of your nodes are running and also configure networking routes to map a node CIDR to your on-prem node. Otherwise, cross-pod networking will not work.

In addition, features like `kubectl exec` and `kubectl logs` likely won't work for any pods running on your on-prem node.

Comment: I'd assume GKE will tax my bandwidth crazily with a vpn, guess we'll have to host kubernetes ourselves :( Disappointed that the ability to host on premise is so limited in reality.

Comment: EDIT: I might be wrong with the comment above, if I'm reading the documentation I could create a single tunnel from my infrastructure to the GKE which will result in 0.05$/h and bandwidth costs of the kubernetes communication. The local infrastructure connections will not be vpn'ed. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Reading https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#vpn it seems that if you send all of your master <-> node traffic through the VPN you will be charged the flat rate that you mentioned.

Comment: Any tutorials you guys know on how to self configure the kubelet? Also, if I had the hash and token could I use kubeadm?

Comment: I don't believe that you can get a hash and token for a node to join a GKE cluster. The easiest way to determine how to configure a kubelet would be to create one in a GKE cluster and reverse engineering the configuration settings (which can change between versions). As mentioned below, GKE On Prep now exists, which is another viable option as well.

Answer (score 2):

Should be available in the near future. You should request the early access: https://cloud.google.com/gke-on-prem/

Comment: Funny, it's only 10kUSD a month, *minimum*.

Answer (score 0):

Using `kubeadm` to join a GKE cluster is not currently possible (`kubeadm` on a node requires a token from a master that [was started using `kubeadm`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/#initializing-your-master)). That would be a cool use case though.